# C - get COM port number of specific device

Tags: c, windows, port

is there a way to automatically detect to which COM port was my device connected on Windows? It is one specific device so I know its name or whatever I need for this.

Right now I have a C program, where I must input COM port number in the console e.g.:

```
printf("COM port number?\n");
scanf("%d",&port_no); 
do_stuff_with_COM_port(port_no);
```

It is annoying to check everytime in windows device manager which number my device is connected to and I want my program to automatically detect port number. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each physical port on your machine has a number that doesn't change. So if you connect your device on the same port every time you shouldn't need this.

But if you might change the port everytime, a solution that might work is :

1. Try to open COM 1

   - If you have an error, port is already open by somebody else, go to Step 3
   - If port does open, move on to Step 2
2. Try to send a message that will be recognized by your device

   - If your receive the expected answer, you know it's the right port.
   - If you don't receive anything (or something nonsense), you know it's not the right COM Port.
3. Move to next available COM Port and repeat until you find it, or that you enumerated all COM Ports

Comment: Nearly:)   Note that the port open may fail because another process has already opened it, (in which case, move on to try the next port, step 5).

Comment: Another variant is to create a separate handler thread for every port.  The one that finds the device with a successful open and poll, wins, the others terminate themselves.  If the serial port handling is already threaded off, (as it often is), then this may be easier and would surely be quicker:)

Comment: @MartinJames updated my answer. Multi-threading is indeed a nice idea.

Comment: I upvoted you anyway, since you had the correct plan, essentially:)